# Validate PHP data types against MySQL fields?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Long time since I've been on but I've hit kind of a head scratcher of a question and I was wondering if anyone could suggest a solution.

The Scenario:

I have number of HTML forms feeding back data via AJAX to a set of PHP PDO query functions.
Although the input will be validated on the form before it is sent I don't want to rely solely  on this.

What I'm asking:

What I'm after is some means of checking that the type of the PHP parameter passed is compatible with the field type its passing data to.
At the moment I'm having to use a huge set of if else statements to check each value in turn and throw Exceptions if there not, so I was wondering if anyone knows of an easier way to check whether a given PHP type is compatible with a given MySQL field type.
I'm sure this must be a problem that's been faced before and if someone could suggest a solution it would save me a great deal of coding and be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since PHP has no typed variables, it would not work I think. You can ofc. query all the mysql fields, and test, if you can cast the given value to the target field type - but everything can be casted to string... to be 100% sure you would need to wrap ALL your variables in a `ValueHolderClass` that is definining value AND type. then you can tell for sure, that a passed 1 (even if castable) should not bes tored into a field of type string/long/double/boolean...

Answer (score 0):

You're putting it wrong.
It is not table structure that dictates the data format, but your application logic. 
Say, there is a string that should contain only a-z letters. You cannot tell it from the field type.
Yes, there are some formats that can be easily validated, like data or integers, but they are mere exceptions and can't be of much help.

Most of time form validation is indeed a long code with custom validations and you cannot avoid it. However, I wouldn't throw exceptions in case of failed validation as it is considered more user friendly to show all the errors occurred, not just one.

If you still want some automated checking - look for some ORM, which will indeed do some validations... for the price of writing much more code in the model, than you writing right now with your validations :)

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm not phrasing my question correctly, basically all I'm asking is if there is an easy means of comparing the **type** of the data being held in a PHP variable (what you get when you use  gettype()) is compatible with the field **type** of the database in which that variables information is to be stored.